# Data between date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have below data in a SQL Server table

```
 Id    Name   StartDate    EndDate
 1      A      2/2/2012     21/2/012
 2      B      3/2/2012     2/2/2014
 3      C      21/2/2012    3/3/2012
 4      D      1/1/2012     3/3/2012
```

I want to fetch all rows which have a `Start Date` and `End Date` that match today's date

Please help.

Comment: match today's date? Month, Day and Year? or Month and Day only?

Comment: Also you titled your question "Data between date", do you want all data where today's date is between Start and EndDate, or exact matching only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to match *ranges* with the current date, then, assuming `StartDate` and `EndDate` are `date` type, you could try the following:

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS date) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
;
```

The above is essentially same as this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
    AND EndDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
;
```

But the first version might yield a worse query plan if the optimiser was unable to translate it as the second version. So, if performance is crucial, you should test first, then decide.

Note that both versions above assume that `EndDate` is inclusive. If it is exclusive, you could take the second version and modify it slightly:

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
    AND EndDate >  CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
;
```

You could further simplify it to this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE StartDate <= GETDATE()
    AND EndDate >  GETDATE()
;
```

But that would probably use implicit conversion, which might affect performance, although I can't be sure to which extent and even less so about whether that would be acceptable to you. Again, you would need to test and compare. Generally, I would start with a simpler version and keep in mind alternatives for the case when I was not (or no longer) satisfied with the present performance.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can understand of "data whose Start Date and End Date match today's date", seems you want to get all data where the StartDate and EndDate are equals to today.

This is the Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE StartDate = cast(getDate() As Date) AND EndDate = cast(getDate() As Date);
```